# Using TableAdapters to insert data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET, I am trying to use a TableAdapter to insert data into in a table, on the TableAdapter I have an SQL query in the Query Builder to "SELECT * FROM users" now I have this piece of code in my register form:

```
 usersTableAdapters.usersTableAdapter user = new usersTableAdapters.usersTableAdapter();

 users.userDataTable usertable = user.GetData();

    string username = System.Convert.ToString(txt_username.Text);
    string password = System.Convert.ToString(txt_password.Text);
```

I am trying to insert the username variable into the username field in my users table and also the password variable into the password field, how ever I do not know how to accomplish doing so. Does anyone have anything in mind to help resolve my situation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try reading full tutorial it will help a lot. What you ask for is a broad answer and not simple specific problem you having. If you are using simple asp.net. You can do something like the following:

```
using (var con=new SqlConnection(yourConString)) {
   var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into users(username,password) values(@username,@pwd)",con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",txt_username.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd",txt_password.Text);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

This can be the code within the click event of your submit button.
Do read here and try to understand the concepts. [ASP.NET Tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_intro.asp)

Comment: What would be the use of the TableAdapter if I used your answer?

Comment: You do not necessarily need a table adapter to insert data from form into the database.